# Testing if a function has an inverse.

Tags: functions, inverse

I was just wondering how you apply the rule:
$$f(x_1) = f(x_2) => x_1 = x_2 $$
on the function:
$$f(x) = x^3 - 9x^2 +33x +45$$

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

EDIT: Yes there should have been a $$9x^2$$ in there.

Comment: I think there should be ".. $-9x^2+$..". You can see that $f'(x)\ge 0$ which implies the inectivity of $f$.

Comment: $-9x^2$ or $-9x$=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $f$ is
$$f'(x)=3x^2-18x+33=3(x^2-6x+11)=3[(x-3)^2+2]$$
which is positive. Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing and hence injective. Nevertheless, an algebraic expression for the inverse it is complicated, because it involves solving of a cubic equation.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple assume that $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1^3+24x_1+45 = x_2^3+24x_2+45$ then we can simplyfy this by saying that $x_1^3-x_2^3 +24(x_1-x_2) =0$

If $x_1 \neq x_2$ then can not be true,thus they must be equal,thus function is injective thus has inverse

Comment: Why ".. $x_1\ne x_2$ then can not be true .." ?

Comment: You state that if $x_1\neq x_2$, then the last equation cannot be $0$; what steps are you taking to prove the claim? (Note: I'm not claiming the statement is false.)

Comment: First line assumes the equality at some two points,then we incorporate the values into function definition.Now if we assume that they are not equal,then the equation can not hold,meaning that also our assumption does not hold

Comment: @Clayton,it is basic mathematics,I do not want to engage in number theory or even deeper into definition of real numbers

Comment: @Mher: $x_1^3-x_2^3=(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)$. Thus his last equation falls out to $(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2+24)=0$, so one of the factors is $0$. The second term cannot be $0$, so $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: @Clayton: I asked that question not just because I don't understand that, while the absence of that explanation in the answer. It should be there!

Comment: @Mher: I completely agree. I am under the impression Vanio didn't know how to prove it and hoped nobody would notice...